# Why isn't netbeans able to run an external javafx application?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Netbeans and Eclipse as well can't run a simple Java application, all it does is open an external java program but the program doesn't actually open, here is my code. What I'm trying to do is create a simple java button and I absolutely have no errors in my program.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. I copied/pasted your code in Netbeans, pressed SHIFT+F6 (on windows) and it worked as expected (the javafx window appeared with the button etc.).

Comment: If you create a new JavaFx program in Netbeans, it automatically creates this exact program.

Comment: What do you guys think might be the issue with mine?